# Duality for modules

Tags: modules, duality-theorems

I'm doing exercises given in Maclane "Homology", and I have problems with the following exercise.

The task is to state the dual of this proposition:

"For submodules $S_t\subset B, \ t\in T$ the following conditions are equivalent:

$(i)$ The diagram $\{j_t: S_t\rightarrow B\}, j_t$ the injection, is universal for ends $S_t$,

$(ii)$ $B=\cup S_t$ and, for each $t_0\in T$, $S_{t_0}\cap (\bigcup\limits_{t\neq t_0}S_t)=0$."

Following Maclane, the dual of a submodule is a quotient module.

It's easy to state dual of the beginning:

"For quotient modules $B/S_t, t\in T$ the following conditions are equivalent:

$(i)$ The diagram $\{j_t: B\rightarrow S_t\}, j_t$ the surjection, is couniversal for ends $S_t$,

$(ii)$ ???"

But I can't get what's the dual of $(ii)$.
Firstly, should I change "and" for "or", and "for each" for "exist"?
Suppose, yes. Secondly, I see two ways to state the dual.
In the first one I just change the module for its factor. So, $B$ is changed for $B/B=0$, $\cup S_t$ for $B/\cup S_t$. We get $0=B/\cup S_t$, which means $\cup S_t=B$ and nothing changed. The same thing for the second equality. So, we get:

1) $(ii)$ $B=\cup S_t$ or, there exists $t_0\in T$, such that $S_{t_0}\cap (\bigcup\limits_{t\neq t_0}S_t)=0$.

And here is the another obvious way:

2) $(ii)$ $0=\cap B/S_t$ or, there exists $t_0\in T$, such that $B/S_{t_0}\cup (\bigcap\limits_{t\neq t_0}B/S_t)=B$."

The question is: Is any of these variants correct? Or are they equivalent?
Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

Given submodules $S,T$ of a module $B$, it is more common to write $S+T$ for their sum, so the smallest submodule containing both $S$ and $T$, rather than use Maclane's notation $S\cup T$.

In the original statement (which is I, Proposition 4.6 in Maclane), we have inclusions $S_t\to B$. Then

- $B=\sum_tS_t$ is equivalent to saying that the natural map $\coprod_tS_t\to B$ is surjective.
- $S_{t_0}\cap\sum_{t\neq t_0}S_t=0$ is equivalent to saying that the composite $S_{t_0}\to B\to B/\sum_{t\neq t_0}S_t$ is injective.

The conclusion is then that the natural map $\coprod_tS_t\to B$ is an isomorphism.

We can now dualise this. We start with epimorphisms $B\to S_t$, and the dual conditions are

- The natural map $B\to\prod_tS_t$ is injective, equivalently the intersection of the kernels of the maps $B\to S_t$ is zero.
- The composite $\mathrm{Ker}(B\to\prod_{t\neq t_0}S_t)\to B\to S_{t_0}$ is surjective.

(I assume the conclusion should be that the natural map $B\to\prod_tS_t$ is an isomorphism, but I don't see this at the moment.)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!
But the conclusion is true in case the set \T of indexes is finite.
What rules did you use to make dual statements? How did you come from \B -> B/sum{S_t} to Ker(B -> prod{S_t}__{t != t0}?

Comment: For the first: “sum of images” becomes “intersections of kernels”, or reverse arrows, “sum” becomes “product” and “surjective” becomes “invective”.

Comment: For the second: reverse arrows in composite map, “invective” becomes “surjective” and “cokernel of map from sum” becomes “kernel of map to product”.